# Will all applet users be impacted by popups after java 7u45?

Tags: java, applet, popup, manifest

There are quite a few discussions regarding this, but I did not find one for the 2 issues combined.

With java 7u45, Oracle introduced Caller-Allowable-Codebase. However, it is not compatible with Trusted-Library. So as they state it, you either get popups for users on version 45, or for users on versions below 40.

https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/7u45_caller_allowable_codebase_and

However, they also impact users on previous versions, by upgrading their security settings, and then showing a popup when we have javascript/applet communication.

https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/7u45_caller_allowable_codebase_and

Do I read this correctly if I sum it up as?

- Users on 7u45 will get popups (unless we remove Trusted-Library, but then we impact users below 7u40)

- Users below 7u45 (ex: 7u25) will still get popups, even though the applet contains Trusted-Library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Q:** Users on 7u45 will get popups (unless we remove Trusted-Library, but then we impact users below 7u40)

**A:** Yes. What we decide (in our company) was to wait and expect Oracle to fix this, which they did with 7u51. I have deployed an applet with the next variables:

> ```
> Manifest-Version: 2.0
>
> Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
>
> Trusted-Library: true
>
> Permissions: all-permissions
>
> Application-Name: My Applet
>
> Codebase: *.mydomain.com
>
> Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *.mydomain.com
>
> Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *.mydomain.com
> ```

and it's working correctly with 7u51, 1.5_22 and 1.6_45. We have found that Java 7u25, 7u40 and 7u45 have a bug regarding the way they check the latest security baseline and the use of LiveConnect, that ended up blocking our applet. You can find more information here: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8027405

At the end we are telling to most of our clients to update to latest Java version in order to use our applet (considering that Oracle has included more security patches with 7u51, it's a good practice to update. In reality, a lot of people don't know how or they can't or want).

- **Q:** Users below 7u45 (ex: 7u25) will still get popups, even though the applet contains Trusted-Library

**A:** It depends if you have another manifest variables along with "Trusted-Library".

- If you include only the var **Caller-Allowable-Codebase**, you will get a prompt.
- If you include only the var **Trusted-Library**, you won't get a prompt.
- If you include both of the mentioned vars, you won't get a prompt.

  With Java 7u51, we have included both vars and we don't get a prompt